# Por que precisei passar o this como parâmetro da função?

Tags: javascript

Tentei colocar uma parte de um código para uma função, para reaproveitar o código, funcionou, só que eu tive que passar o `this` como parâmetro, não sei se é correto fazer isso.

Segue o código como estava e como eu deixei:

```
// como estava
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table').dataTable({

        // code ...

        "drawCallback": function ( settings ) {

            var api = this.api();
            var rows = api.rows( {page:'current'} ).nodes();
            var last=null;

            api.column(0, {page:'current'} ).data().each( function ( group, i ) {
                if ( last !== group ) {
                    $(rows).eq( i ).before(
                        '<tr class="info"><td colspan="2">'+group+'</td></tr>'
                    );

                    last = group;
                }
            } );

            // code ...
        }
    });
});
```

e como eu deixei

```
//como deixei
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table').dataTable({

        // code ...

        "drawCallback": function ( settings ) {

            groupColumnToRowDT(this, 0, 2);

            // code ...
        }
    });
});
```

e a função que criei

```
function groupColumnToRowDT(t, column, colspan) {
    var api = t.api();
    var rows = api.rows( {page:'current'} ).nodes();
    var last=null;

    api.column(column, {page:'current'} ).data().each( function ( group, i ) {
        if ( last !== group ) {
            $(rows).eq( i ).before(
                '<tr class="info"><td colspan="'+colspan+'">'+group+'</td></tr>'
            );

            last = group;
        }
    } );
}
```

Comment: Ué, pra passar o `datatable` como parâmetro da função.

Comment: ok, mas esta certo então da forma que fiz?

Comment: Funciona da forma que deveria?

Comment: funciona, mas me pareceu uma gambiarra, fiz, testei, funcionou, mas fiquei dando uma olhada e não me pareceu a coisa mais bela...kkk

Comment: Se funciona da forma que deveria, tá certo. Provavelmente você deve estar acostumado com o `this` em outras linguagens de programação. No JavaScript a história muda um pouco, por isso o estranhamento.